# My wireless drops internet connection

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking

My laptop randomly drops connection to the internet. I'm running Windows 7 Home Premium 64-bit. I've just upgraded from Windows Vista Home Premium 32-bit. My laptop doesn't lose connection to my network, just the internet. I'm not sure how to describe or what really is wrong :(

EDIT: seems that it was a problem with my wireless router, changed that it hasn't lost connection since, thanks for all the help.

Comment: I have the same issue.  What router are you using, and what kind of wireless card is in your computer?

Comment: its the standard wireless card in my Toshibia L300-1AS laptop. I have a wireless Belkin N Class router.

Comment: Click the start orb, type `devmgmt.msc` then press enter.  Then click the small arrow next to "Network Adapters".  What is listed in that section?

Comment: Also, are you using an N connection or a G connection? Do you know if your N router is dual-band?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your DSL router and check if the Internet is working well. So maybe the problem is with your Internet connection, and not with the operating system.

If you are using ADSL, static in the line would hurt the connection.

Also it is better to use ADSL filter (Called splitter sometimes).

Is the connection working normally on any other device? Or it has the same symptoms?

Comment: Everything else on the connection is fine, no settings have changed, just the OS update was fine before then

Comment: Try disabling the Internet Security application if you have one. I read somewhere that it solved the issue for somebody.

Comment: that doesnt seem to be much help

Answer (score 1):

@Arch, unfortunately, I think your issue is highly discussed in the [Microsoft answers forum here](http://social.answers.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/w7network/thread/0014801b-7e82-4bb6-a8e7-e8867eb3fcee); and without resolution.

If it were my guess, it’s likely a DHCP lease timeout issue on your access point as Windows 7 handles DHCP differently than Vista, a driver issue on your network card, or a configuration change for DHCP-in on the advanced firewall settings.  Hope the post helps

Comment: that link doesn't seem to be much help for me but thanks

Comment: Seems like a likely cause, though.  I have an issue identical to OP's but the only thing in common is Windows 7... Different router, different WLAN card.

Answer (score 1):

I would first check for a driver update for the wireless card in your laptop.

Second, try to turn off iPv6 as described here : [How To Disable IPv6 In Windows 7](http://www.addictivetips.com/windows-tips/how-to-disable-ipv6-in-windows-7/).

Comment: that hasn't fixed my problem it still randomly drops and why would it have been okay before but not now?

Comment: It is probably a matter of the driver. You can try installing in Win7 the driver you had in Vista (they are compatible).

Answer (score 0):

Harry's turn off ipv6 thought is probable.  Another thing you might look in to is setting DNS to an external server as opposed to using the router's built in dns.  In my experience with running connection intensive applications(think torrent), it has tried to resolve all hostnames for a really large number of connections and has unpredictable crashes.  In my case it had to do with trying to hold/push through too much DNS data on the router.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a Hail Mary will do the trick:

Does anyone happen to be [using a microwave](http://www.guardian.co.uk/technology/askjack/2009/jun/18/wifi-microwave-interference) when the internet cuts out?

Answer (score 0):

I recently had this problem and have been on the phone with my cable company numerous times to solve the issue.

I finally found someone technically competent that could help me. He ruled out the service to my cable modem in the house was a problem by asking if the lights on the modem changed when the service went out. They did not change at all. This observation led him to ask where my wireless router was located. He mentioned:

If your wireless router is next to other appliances like:

a computer
a tv
a stereo
a cd player
Then, there may be wireless interference coming from those appliances causing your connection to drop for a period of time.

By moving the wireless router away from these appliances I have not seen the issue reoccur.